# Achieve behavior of "scroll-snap-stop: always" in Chromium

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

We're currently implementing a slider based on CSS Scroll-Snapping. Since we want to avoid users to skip slides via fast swipe, we've simply added `scroll-snap-stop: always` to our scroll container, however this value is not supported by Chrome anymore. Experimenting with touch events to stop scrolling depending on the speed of the swipe gesture itself turned out to be very tricky. Do you have any suggestion how to implement the behavior of `scroll-snap-stop: always`?